# Python Switcher Unreachable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple dictionary mapping but I'm getting an error stating that `switcher` is unreachable.

```
def option_select(option):
    switcher = {
        1: "Option One",
        2: "Option Two",
        3: "Option Three",
        4: "Option Four",
        0: sys.exit()
    }
    return switcher.get(option, "Invalid choice")


print("Please select an option:")
print("1: Add a new student.")
print("2: Delete an existing student.")
print("3: List all students.")
print("4: Search for a student.")
print("0: Exit")
optionChoice = int(input("Selection: "))

option_select(optionChoice)
```

Comment: The definition of `switcher` will execute `sys.exit()` and your program will end.

Comment: Could you explain that logic further? Why if `1` is given as an argument will it still drop down to `0`?

Comment: Would make more sense if all the values are functions, i.e. `switcher = {1: do_foo, 2: do_bar, ..., 0: sys.exit}`. (Note: no `()`)

Comment: @Colin747 Because it is not a `switch` statement. It's a dictionary. Your definition creates the whole dictionary, not just whichever bit you end up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `switcher` will execute `sys.exit()` and your program will end.

Your use of `switcher` is not a switch statement; it is a dictionary, in which you map the key `0` to the return value of `sys.exit()`. In order to determine this value and create the dictionary, `sys.exit()` is executed. `sys.exit()` exits your program.

The easiest fix is just to deal with exit separately:

```
def option_select(option):
    if option==0:
        sys.exit()
    switcher = {
        1: "Option One",
        2: "Option Two",
        3: "Option Three",
        4: "Option Four",
    }
    return switcher.get(option, "Invalid choice")
```

Or you could write your `switcher` so that each value is callable:

```
switcher = {
    1: add_student,
    2: delete_student,
    3: list_students,
    4: search_students,
    0: sys.exit,
}
```

and define the values as functions, and then you can *call* the result you get from the dictionary to do whatever it is supposed to do.

E.g.

```
switcher[option]()
```

Comment: I now have the following, but if I give `1` as an option it's still calling `1` and `2` - is this the correct way to use this? (I come from a Java background and I'm trying to use this like a switch statement.   
 `switcher = {
        1: create_new_student(),
        2: test_function(),
        0: sys.exit
    }`

Comment: No, remove the `()`. Otherwise you are calling the funtion while you define the dictionary.

Comment: I tried that but the function does not seem to be called when I pass in `1` as an option.

Comment: You can call it after you get it from the dictionary. E.g. `switcher[option]()`.

Comment: OK, looks like it's working. I assumed you meant something like `return switcher[option]()`